# How possible a hard drive that used to have bad sectors now have none?

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors

I have a 3TB hard drive for which I recently received a SMART alert saying there's about 16 bad sectors on it :

```
C5 Current Pending Sector Count 0x10
C6 Uncorrectable Sector Count 0x10
```

I ran `CHKDSK d: /B` which took nearly 8 hours, it fixed these bad sectors and no others were discovered.

However, running [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) again, the count has gone to zero, how possible ?

Particularly, is this something to worry about ?

Comment: *"how possible ?"* -- Sector remapping.  Chkdsk can remap bad sectors at the filesystem level.  The HDD controller can also remap at the drive level.  Perform the long/extended SMART test if you're concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible reasons.  The first is that you need to take a look at the value for the reallocated sector count.  When you try to write to a bad sector, if the drive is physically unable to record and read back good data there, it will remap that logical sector to a different location on the disk ( they come with a pool of reserved sectors for this purpose ).

The other possibility is that while the data that once was there has become corrupt, when you try to write new data, it takes and can be read back just fine.  In that case, the sector is no longer marked as pending, nor did it need to be reallocated.  This tends to happen if you lose power in the middle of a write: the sector being written is corrupted, but if you try to write to it again, the physical medium is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Monitor and if any bad sectors show up again, get ready to change drive.

Drives have built in technology to handle some bad sectors.  Sometimes the automatic correction does not catch them.