# Why did the uncorrectable sector count decrease?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

A few months ago, a Seagate ST31000528AS (1 TB) hard drive was reporting 8 uncorrectable sectors on CrystalDiskInfo (which triggered the "warning" status), so I ramped up the backup frequency anticipating the number to keep increasing.

However, today, I checked the drive, and the uncorrectable sector count (SMART field C6) had dropped to zero, and CrystalDiskInfo was reporting "OK" on the drive again.

How could this have happened? "Uncorrectable" means uncorrectable - there's no way the hard drive could have brought back those sectors from ECC. The reallocated sectors count (SMART field 05) is also at zero. This [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/897821/how-possible-a-hard-drive-that-used-to-have-bad-sectors-now-have-none) involves having run a comprehensive `CHKDSK /b`, but I have done no such thing recently. Is this a bug in the hard drive controller? Did it resolve that there is nothing stored in these sectors anymore, and so has hidden away the sectors as if they had never existed?

I have read (ad nauseum) the usual lecture about backups and drive replacement: "If you have to ask if the drive is failing, the answer is always yes." I'd just like an explanation as to why the drive *was* indicating failure, but is not anymore.

Comment: I'm wondering if the value is only 6 bit and rolled over or something, 2*2*2*2*2*2 is 64, high enough that you should be replacing the disk... but dumb if that's what actually happened.

Answer (score -1):

Apologies for the late response. I assume you've either solved the issue or simply replaced the drive by now, but the question merits a response imo.

Hard drives (and SSD's) can have bad sectors, which they usually don't report to the OS unless absolutely critical. What they do in such a case is to try and read the data in the bad sector where possibly and move it to a spare sector if available, then silently mark the bad sector as unusable, without the OS knowing.

Sometimes simply deleting and writing new data to the disk will do the trick, sometimes a full format is needed, during which all the bits on the entire disk are rewritten to "0". The critical cases I mentioned earlier usually involve physical damage to the disk that causes so many corrupt sectors that there aren't enough spares available, in which case the disk will report imminent failure to the OS.

In some (rare) cases you can still format the 'failing' disk for re-use, though it's advised not to use it for anything other than temp storage for data you don't mind losing, like logs that are overwritten daily or weekly anyway.

Comment: It's possible a full disk erase might fix it, but unlikely that it would lower the count. My understanding is that once an uncorrectable error occurs on a sector, that sector will never be tried or used again. But maybe the drive did try it again - who knows?